# How to create conditional dummies "before the event" with dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I'm trying create a condition dummy (X) with the rule

set X=1 if Y=1 the last two years before the NA (only count once!).

To give an example: this is a sample from my data:

```
year    country Y
1990    Bahamas 1
1991    Bahamas NA
1992    Bahamas NA
1993    Bahamas 0
1994    Bahamas 1
1995    Bahamas 1
1996    Bahamas NA
1997    Bahamas 1
1998    Bahamas NA
1999    Bahamas 1
2000    Bahamas NA
2001    Bahamas 1
2002    Bahamas 1
2003    Bahamas 0
2004    Bahamas NA
2005    Bahamas 0
2006    Bahamas 0
2007    Bahamas 1
2008    Bahamas NA
2009    Bahamas 1
2010    Bahamas 1
2011    Bahamas 1
```

And here is how the X dummy should look like:

```
year    country Y   X1
1990    Bahamas 1   1
1991    Bahamas NA  0
1992    Bahamas NA  0
1993    Bahamas 0   0
1994    Bahamas 1   1
1995    Bahamas 1   0
1996    Bahamas NA  0
1997    Bahamas 1   1
1998    Bahamas NA  0
1999    Bahamas 1   1
2000    Bahamas NA  0
2001    Bahamas 1   1
2002    Bahamas 1   0
2003    Bahamas 0   0
2004    Bahamas NA  0
2005    Bahamas 0   0
2006    Bahamas 0   0
2007    Bahamas 1   1
2008    Bahamas NA  0
2009    Bahamas 1   0
2010    Bahamas 1   0
2011    Bahamas 1   0
```

This is a bit too complicated for me. I've been reading about dplyr which seems to be a relevant package here. My readings has so far taken me to this cod

```
df %>% mutate(X=ifelse(Y >0) & lag(Y,2,))
```

I get the error:

> argument "yes" is missing, with no default

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. Should I put the "ifelse" before the "lag" as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain how column `X1` was created? The logic isn't clear to me yet.

Comment: X=1 if Y was =1 in the last two years before the NA. From the example: in 1996 the Y had the NA.  So,  had the Y variable value=1 in the last two years (e.g 1994 and 1995)? Yes, in 1994 - therefore X==1 in 1994.

Comment: If we had the NA in 2000, that the Y was =0 for 1998 and 1999, then the X for 1998 and 1999 should be =0. But if we had in 1998 or in the 1999 (that is two year befor the NA) then the X would have been ==1 that year.

Comment: I realize that this is not easy to explain. In my head everything makes sense until I start to write it down. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Sorry @Goulou, the pattern you're looking for is still not clear. Is it `0, 0, NA`?  Could you specify the pattern you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! `0, 0, NA`. So if `0, 0, NA` then X=0. If `1, 0, NA`  or `1, 1, NA`, then the X shoud be =1 that  first specificyear.

Comment: @Goulou Perhaps, logic is understood  correctly by me. Please have a look at answer and confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- readr::read_table(
"year    country Y
1990    Bahamas 1
1991    Bahamas NA
1992    Bahamas NA
1993    Bahamas 0
1994    Bahamas 1
1995    Bahamas 1
1996    Bahamas NA
1997    Bahamas 1
1998    Bahamas NA
1999    Bahamas 1
2000    Bahamas NA
2001    Bahamas 1
2002    Bahamas 1
2003    Bahamas 0
2004    Bahamas NA
2005    Bahamas 0
2006    Bahamas 0
2007    Bahamas 1
2008    Bahamas NA
2009    Bahamas 1
2010    Bahamas 1
2011    Bahamas 1
")

expected_output <- readr::read_table(
"year    country Y   X1
1990    Bahamas 1   1
1991    Bahamas NA  0
1992    Bahamas NA  0
1993    Bahamas 0   0
1994    Bahamas 1   1
1995    Bahamas 1   0
1996    Bahamas NA  0
1997    Bahamas 1   1
1998    Bahamas NA  0
1999    Bahamas 1   1
2000    Bahamas NA  0
2001    Bahamas 1   1
2002    Bahamas 1   0
2003    Bahamas 0   0
2004    Bahamas NA  0
2005    Bahamas 0   0
2006    Bahamas 0   0
2007    Bahamas 1   1
2008    Bahamas NA  0
2009    Bahamas 1   0
2010    Bahamas 1   0
2011    Bahamas 1   0
")
```

Identify the groups ending with `NA`, find the position of the first `1` in the `Y` column, create the `X1` column with `1`s in found positions:

```
res <-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(is.na(lag(Y))), add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(first_year_at_1 = match(1, Y) * any(is.na(Y)) * any(tail(Y, 3) == 1L), 
         X1 = {x <- integer(length(Y)) ; x[first_year_at_1] <- 1L ; x}) %>% 
  ungroup()

all.equal(select(res, -grp, -first_year_at_1), expected_output)

# [1] TRUE
```

*(Note: if there are different countries in the real dataset, you might want to group by `country` first to avoid undesirable effects at the junction of countries. I edited my answer accordingly).*

Comment: I get this "Error: assignments are forbidden"

Comment: And what is `packageVersion("dplyr")`? (mine is `0.7.4`. In case yours is an earlier version, can you update with `install.packages("dplyr")`?)

Comment: With the real data. I can't see any difference in the pattern between the sample I provided and the real data I have

Comment: Trying to figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Do you think it might be because I have different countries in the data?

Comment: version 0.4.3. Upgrading now

Comment: It worked and it's almost there. It works for the most cases but really 100%. It's my fault, I haven't been clear, I think. The dummy should only be sensitive to the last two years before the NA. So this pattern: `0,0,NA`. If both are 0's, then the X shold be =1. If the Y is `1,0,NA` or 1,1,NA` the X should be =1 that specific year. This code has generated lots of 1's the first year after the NA.

Comment: @Goulou See my edit, I added `* any(tail(Y, 3) == 1L)`

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be found using `dplyr` package. The approach is to create a group ending with `NA`. Then the `first` row with for a group having `Y == 1` and that group's `last Y` is NA then `x1` is set as `1` otherwise `X1` will be set as `0`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Grp = cumsum(is.na(lag(Y))))  %>%
  mutate(X1 = ifelse(row_number()== min(which(Y==1)) & is.na(last(Y)) , 1, 0 )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Grp) %>%
  as.data.frame()


#    year country  Y X1
# 1  1990 Bahamas  1  1
# 2  1991 Bahamas NA  0
# 3  1992 Bahamas NA  0
# 4  1993 Bahamas  0  0
# 5  1994 Bahamas  1  1
# 6  1995 Bahamas  1  0
# 7  1996 Bahamas NA  0
# 8  1997 Bahamas  1  1
# 9  1998 Bahamas NA  0
# 10 1999 Bahamas  1  1
# 11 2000 Bahamas NA  0
# 12 2001 Bahamas  1  1
# 13 2002 Bahamas  1  0
# 14 2003 Bahamas  0  0
# 15 2004 Bahamas NA  0
# 16 2005 Bahamas  0  0
# 17 2006 Bahamas  0  0
# 18 2007 Bahamas  1  1
# 19 2008 Bahamas NA  0
# 20 2009 Bahamas  1  0
# 21 2010 Bahamas  1  0
# 22 2011 Bahamas  1  0
# 
#
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"year    country Y
1990    Bahamas 1
1991    Bahamas NA
1992    Bahamas NA
1993    Bahamas 0
1994    Bahamas 1
1995    Bahamas 1
1996    Bahamas NA
1997    Bahamas 1
1998    Bahamas NA
1999    Bahamas 1
2000    Bahamas NA
2001    Bahamas 1
2002    Bahamas 1
2003    Bahamas 0
2004    Bahamas NA
2005    Bahamas 0
2006    Bahamas 0
2007    Bahamas 1
2008    Bahamas NA
2009    Bahamas 1
2010    Bahamas 1
2011    Bahamas 1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```