# Conditional dummy for specific years in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to generate a conditional dummy variable ”X" with the following rule

```
set X=1 if Y is =1, two years prior to the NA.
In other words, X=1/0 depending on [0/1=year1,0/1=year2,NA].
```

For example, as seen below, if  the pattern for Y is `0,0,NA` then the X variable is =0 for all  the two years prior to the NA. If the pattern for Y is `0,1,NA` or `1,0,NA` then the X =1 . To be clear, if `1,1,NA` then the X=1 that  first specific year, it should only count once (X=1), not twice.

The code that I have now (thanks  @Auréle, from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556268/how-to-create-conditional-dummies-before-the-event-with-dplyr-in-r))  is the closest that I have to generate it.

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(is.na(lag(Y))), add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(first_year_at_1 = match(1, Y) * any(is.na(Y)) * any(tail(Y, 3) == 1L), 
         X = {x <- integer(length(Y)) ; x[first_year_at_1] <- 1L ; x}) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

However, it doesn’t really generate what I described above. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Below you can see my sample data with the desired outcome ”X” dummy in it.

```
data <- structure(list(year = c(1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L), country = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Canada", 
"Cuba", "Dominican Republic", "Haiti", "Jamaica"), class = "factor"), 
    Y = c(1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA), X = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-110L))
```

Comment: This question could benefit from simplification and clearer description of the problem.  For example, you don't mention anything about grouping by country, but you do this in your code.  Also, the pattern you are trying to achieve is not fully specified, and there are many edge cases.  I would suggest you come up with a very simple example that clearly shows the set of rules and operations you need to perform, and show that in your post.  Right now it's a little confusing and complicated, which makes it difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest the question is not 100% clear, but I thought I'd give it a shot, so here it goes:

```
data_new <- data_1 %>% 
  mutate(Y_2 = ifelse(is.na(Y), -1, Y)) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(X_2 = ifelse((Y_2==1 & 
                         lead(Y_2, 1) == -1 & 
                         (lag(Y_2,1)!=1 | is.na(lag(Y_2,1)))) | 
                        (Y_2==1 & lead(Y_2, 2) == -1 ), 
                      1, 0))
```

basically I formulated the condition as follows:

X is 1 in two cases:

- if Y == 1 and Y after two years is NA
- or if (Y == 1) and (Y next year is NA) and (Y on the year before is not 1)

A couple of notes:

- Since we can't use NAs in comparisons, I used the column Y_2 to replace the NAs with the value -1, and then used it in the comparison
- The condition (Y on the year before is not 1) also might cause problems in the first recorded row (year) of each group (country) when Y == 1, which is why I included this case also in the condition (i.e `(lag(Y_2,1)!=1 | is.na(lag(Y_2,1)))`)
- Like mentioned in the comment by @andrew_reece, the pattern you're trying to get has a lot of edge cases, only one of which is in the point above, other example might be if Y == 1 in the last couple of years for some country, how would you handle that?

Try considering a more specified description of your conditions based on the data you have

hope this helps